# How to make as few changes as possible in a collection of doublets?

Tags: combinatorics

My apologies if the title is not clear, but I will try to explain my problem as best I can.

I need to generate a list of objects, each object being of the form : $((\theta_i), (\theta_j, \phi_j))$. Each object is therefore composed of two sub-objects, the first being a real number $(\theta) \in [0 \ ; \pi/2]$, the second a doublet of real numbers $(\theta, \phi) \in [0 \ ; \pi/2] \times [0 \ ; 2\pi]$.

I would like to be able to generate, for a number N, a list of N objects respecting certain rules:

1. for an object $((\theta_i), (\theta_j, \phi_j))$ to have interest, it is obligatory that one finds in the list its complementary of the form $((\theta_j), (\theta_i, 2\pi - \phi_i \mod 2\pi))$.
2. The list should be constructed so as to have as few "movements" as possible. What I call a movement is a change of one of the two sub-objects. **The list is thus ordered.**

Let me explain this with an example: here is a list :
$\{((\theta_1),(\theta_2, \phi_2)), ((\theta_2),(\theta_1, 2\pi - \phi_2)), ((\theta_3),(\theta_2, 2\pi - \phi_3)), ((\theta_2),(\theta_3, \phi_3))\}$

In this list each object is useful because each one has its complement also included in the list. However, the number of moves here is 8 (two moves to create the two sub-objects of the first object, and then two moves to move from one object to the other). However, it would have been possible to reduce the number of movements by swapping two objects:
$\{((\theta_1),(\theta_2, \phi_2)), ((\theta_2),(\theta_1, 2\pi - \phi_2)), ((\theta_2),(\theta_3, \phi_3)), ((\theta_3),(\theta_2, 2\pi - \phi_3))\}$

Here, moving from object $((\theta_2),(\theta_1, 2\pi - \phi_2))$ to object $((\theta_2),(\theta_3, \phi_3))$ required only one movement, as the first sub-object was the same for both.

I am interested in a solution if anyone has an idea, or any advice.